# Convert string to dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, qr-code

I have a QR code scanner which reads QR codes as a string. There are no options to detect it as a dictionary. So the only solution would be to convert it to a dictionary (i think). Keep in mind I am using swift and using AVFoundation, which is from apple.

[image]

This QR code would print out ["test": "test123"] as a string. How would I convert it to a dictionary?

Comment: First comes to mind is to convert the string to JSON then to Dictionary.

Comment: Did you created yourself? If yes, what about using JSON instead? `["test": "test123"]` => `{"test": "test123"}`?

Comment: Yes, I created it myself. Ok, I will do that instead, didn't think of that. I know how to convert JSON to Dictionary. I would suggest your comment as an answer.

Comment: @TheNitram The string already is JSON.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, i said i didnt think of that

Comment: @EliasKnudsen As you can see in my comment, I was replying to TheNitram's comment, not to you.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, hard to see on my phone while walking

Comment: @rmaddy I haven't really played with QR so I'm not sure it I can feed its output directly to JSONSerializer. Maybe you can come up with a better answer. We'll sure appreciate it.

Comment: @TheNitram Your answer is fine. It converts the JSON string to a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've came up with. Output is not dictionary though.

```
let test = "[\"test\": \"test123\"]"
    let data = test.data(using: .utf8)!
    do{
        let output = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:String]
        print ("\(String(describing: output))")
    }
    catch {
        print (error)
    }
```